# Word ageing: what reliable bibliographical references can be recommended?

Tags: etymology, semantics, historical-linguistics, language-change, lexical-semantics

I have encountered the notion of "**word ageing**". Lexemes (unless and until replaced through internal or external innovation) grow older and older, and with time they tend to (1) acquire some additional meanings (***increase in polysemy***) and (2) lose morphological transparency (***phonological erosion***).

Now, I have seen this discussed in connection with *lexical (in)stability*: If the above holds, then, conversely, if we find words within the (*native*) **basic vocabulary** (such as that represented by the ***Swadesh list***) that are both morphologically transparent [compounds or derivatives] and display very little polysemy, or even none, this means that, in all likelihood, we are dealing with (*relatively recent*) **innovations**.

It appears that the relative stability correlates with textual **frequency** (i.e. *the more frequent* the lexeme, the *higher* its stability), but this is the semantic side of the equation. I wonder if this can be true of the form, that is: (a) *Is the form also generally preserved better in the stable part of the lexicon?* And (b) *is it thanks to the higher frequency?* And also, if we "measured" the proportion of ***irregularities*** (appearing randomly, though not causelessly) within a Swadesh-like list, (c) *would they be **lower or higher** than the ones found in a comparable list of culture-specific lexemes?*

These are the questions I would like to get answers to. Could anyone possibly recommend some reliable bibliographical references to works discussing these phenomena (i.e. mainly *frequency/stability*, *polysemy/semantic ageing*, *phonological erosion/[morpho]phonological ageing*)? I doubt introductory textbooks will be of any use to me, but I might be wrong, so I will be grateful for just anything relevant.

Comment: Well, many if not most phonological changes seen to occur at word edges, and that does result in erosion over time. As for polysemy, that's unavoidable since the language changes when the context does, and contexts change continually and unpredictably, so meanings get stretched over new metaphors and set adrift. As for a bibliography, start with Trask's _Historical Linguistics_.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I did know, of course, that both the form and meaning evolve in this way; what I wasn't sure about, however, was whether it holds, to the same or a comparable degree, for (1) all groups (however defined) of languages, and (2) all parts of their lexicon, e.g. "_basic_" vs. "_cultural_" vocabulary. I've noticed, for instance, that some Athabaskan languages seem to have a lot of morphologically transparent compounds in their basic vocabulary, which seems to point to a relatively recent massive wave of innovations. Should I update my question accordingly?

Comment: @jlawler I have just revised the question quite a bit. I hope it is a bit clearer now what kind of answers I have been looking for. Thank you for the _Trask_ reference - I am sure it will be helpful in one way or another.